# Is $\cos(\frac{\pi}{x})$ uniformly continuous on (0,1)?

Tags: real-analysis

I have to use the definition of uniform continuity to disprove that $\cos(\frac{\pi}{x})$ is uniformly continuous, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Who is the sick person who puts downvotes? Or is someone who thinks that knowing little is knowing much? Each downvote, should be accompanied by justification or identification either.

Comment: If $f(x)=\cos \frac{\pi}{x}$ you have $|f(x)-f(x')|$ is not independant of the variable $x$ at the neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: @Ataulfo. It would be so nice to see that happening !

Comment: @Ataulfo I guess it's because the question shows absolutely no effort.

Comment: @anderstood: yes, you are OK maybe (note however what Matheusz said).

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\cos\left(\frac \pi x\right)$ and take $x_n=\frac1n$ and $y_n=\frac1{n+1}$ then we can make $|x_n-y_n|$ small as we want for large $n$ but $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|=2$. Can you take it from here?